# Fuzzy string matching with support for words in multiple languages or different words with same meaning

Tags: c#, algorithm, string-matching, fuzzy-search, multiple-languages

I'm looking for an algorithm that would support Fuzzy string matching like Damerau–Levenshtein or DICE or Longest Common Subsequence. But this algorithm should have the ability to match words in different languages and consider them equal when spelled in their respective languages or close if spelled incorrectly in their respective languages.

I think an example will better explain what I mean (**1,2,5,6** form a group the same for **3,4,7,8**) :

```
A well spelled cmpny name   A well spelled term we can find in multiple languages
    _____________           ___________________________________________________

1 StackOverflow             Question            // would easily match with 2
2 StackOverflow             Frage               // would easily match with 1
3 Swiss Life                Pension Fund        // would easily match with 4
4 Swiss Life                Caisse de pension   // would easily match with 3
```

Also, I would like them to be matched easily even if spelled incorrectly :

```
A misspelled company name   A misspelled term we can find in multiple languages
_________________________   ____________________________________________________

5 stackverflow              qestion        // would match easily with 1,2,6
6 SteckOverflw              frge           // would match easily with 1,2,5
7 Swisslife                 pension        // would match easily with 3,4,8
8 swizerland life           caisse pension // would match easily with 3,4,7
```

By match I mean having a good score. And I've actually tried to achieve this kind of comparison using Dice and lcs but the issue is that it's very weak against words spelled in multiple languages.

Look Dice coef in a tricky case :

```
name 1                  name 2                      coef
____________________    ______________________      _______________

migros pensionskasse    sig pensionskasse           0.769230769
migros pensionskasse    caisse pensions migros      0.727272727
```

The above first is better only because `pensionskasse` is matched and is larger than `migros` or `sig`. But because `pensionskasse` means `caisse de pension` the second should be better in the algorithm I seek.

I know the possible words that can be spelled in various languages so I can make a dictionary with the connections between those words.

I also could get rid of them (the multi-languages words) but then I would loose some insightful information to build groups based on those connections.

Has anyone seen an implementation that looks like this ? Ideally in C# ?

Comment: I have almost a same problem.. please help if someone have an idea